# Extract multiple Google calendars to single Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I'm using a Google script to extract data from a resource calendar. The script works as intended to extract a single calendar, but I would like to extract multiple resource calendars into 1 sheet. Can someone point me in the right direction? I've looked at creating an array to include multiple calendars into 'mycal', but I couldn't get it to run. Thanks

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){

var mycal = "engelska.se_xxxx@resource.calendar.google.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

var today = new Date();
var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal).getEventsForDay(today);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

sheet.clearContents();  

var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,14);
range.setValues(header);

for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var myformula_placeholder = '';
var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent()]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,14);
range.setValues(details);

var cell=sheet.getRange(row,7);
cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
cell.setNumberFormat('.00');  

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make mycal into an array you will need a second loop to step thru that array and the variable assignment based on mycal will need to be in that loop. the events loop you already have will also need to be inside that loop. Because the number of events in each calendar could be different the best way to maintain the row counter is to declare it before both loops and increment it after you write to a row.

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet(){


  var mycal = ["engelska.se_xxxx@resource.calendar.google.com",
             "calenderaddress2",
             "calenderaddress3",
             "calenderaddress4"];//note , between address, no , after last




  //here we do all the things that need to be done only once.

  var today = new Date();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.clearContents();  

  var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event"]]
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,14);
  range.setValues(header);


  var row=2;// this needs to be outside the loops in order to use it as a counter in nested loops


  for (var j = 0; j< mycal.lengh; j++){
    //here we do the things we do once per calander

    var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal[j]).getEventsForDay(today);//refer to the calender in mycal based on loop counter
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal[j]);//refer to the calender in mycal based on loop counter
    //incerting a header for each calander would be done here. make sure to increment row

    for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {

      var myformula_placeholder = '';
      var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent()]];
      var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,14);
      range.setValues(details);

      var cell=sheet.getRange(row,7);
      cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
      cell.setNumberFormat('.00');  

      row++; //increment row counter.

    }

  }
}
```